# python adding tuple to list based on string representation

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

so I have this string dictionary of tuples:

```
data = '604452601061112210'

NewDict = {'60': ('PUSH1', 1), '61': ('PUSH2', 2), '52' : ('MSTORE', 0 ), '12' : ('ADD', 0)}
```

im trying to scan the string for the dictionary keys, to add to add the dict key to the list, along with the following bytes within the string, for example, it should print out in this order:

```
[PUSH1 44, MSTORE, PUSH1 10, PUSH2 1122, ADD]
```

however, my output is:

```
['PUSH1 44', 'MSTORE ', 'PUSH1 10', 'PUSH2 2210']
```

this is my code:

```
i = 0
L = []

while i < len(data):
    op = data[i:i+2]

    for item in NewDict:
        if op in item:
            i += NewDict[item][1] * 2

            pep = NewDict[item][0] + ' ' + data[i:i+NewDict[item][1] * 2]
            L.append(pep)     
    else:
        i += 2

print(L)
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why do you loop through `NewDict`? Just use `NewDict[op]` to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're incrementing `i` by `NewDict[item][1] * 2` *before* you extract the parameter after the operator. You should do this after extracting.

You also don't need the `for item in NewDict:` loop, just access the element of `NewDict` directly.

```
while i < len(data):
    op = data[i:i+2]
    if op in NewDict:
        opname, oplen = NewDict[op]
        param = data[i+2:i+2+oplen*2]
        L.append(opname + " " + param)
        i += 2 + oplen*2
    else:
        i += 2
```

Even after fixing this you don't get `ADD` in the result because the last op in `data` is `10`, not `12`.

Comment: that works great except it doesn't add the last dict key to the end of the list, which is 'ADD'

Comment: `data` ends with `10`, but `ADD` is `12`.

Comment: @kieron Change to `data = '604452601061112212'` and it ends with `ADD`.

Comment: oops my bad, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
L = []

while i < len(data):
    op = data[i:i+2]

    for item in NewDict:
        if op in item:
            i += NewDict[item][1] * 2

            pep = NewDict[item][0] + ' ' + data[i:i+NewDict[item][1] * 2]
            L.append(pep)     
    else:
        i += 2

print(','.join(L))
```

`','.join(L)` removes the quotes around it. Hope this is what you meant? you can't really add a tuple to a list because those are different things. A tuple is, easy said, an unchangeable list.